# HAXM not working properly

Tags: android, sdk, haxm

[image]

I am using DELL inspiron n4010 with i3 generation 1 processor. Its showing me VT- enabled but I am not able to run the HAXM driver in my android simulator. The drivers have been installed successfullly. Please help me out.
Actually I am not able to see this  while running the avd with intel processor.

Answer (score 1):

It should not supposed to run on android simulator(Emulator) actually YOu have to create an emulator with intel Atom(x86), and the driver will make this emulator run faster than the other emulator.
[Check this link](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html)

Comment: Also dont forget to check "Use Host GPU" while creating emulator.

Answer (score 0):

you should check how much disk space you have allocated while installing HAXM and how much disk space your virtual devices (in AVD) use. Perhaps you allocate more disk space to the emulated devices than you have specified when installing HAXM.